# How do I move the first arrays into list of array on the second array?

Tags: php, arrays

---first array---

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string ' doctor' (length=47)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string ' Contact: Rob miller' (length=22)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string ' Location: anywhere 23 ' (length=37)
      1 => string ' ME 04848' (length=10)
```

--- second array---

```
array (size=2)
  'notelp' => string '(xxx) xxx-xxxx ' (length=15)
  'site' => string 'http://www.example.com/' (length=33)
```

what I want is:

```
array (size=2)
  'notelp' => string '(xxx) xxx-xxxx ' (length=15)
  'site' => string 'http://www.example.com/' (length=33)
  'profession' => string ' doctor' (length=5)
  'contact' => string ' Contact: Rob miller' (length=22)
  'address' => string ' Location: anywhere 23 , ME 04848'
```

Comment: Have you tried something? :)

Comment: How are you getting those arrays?

Comment: Manipulate that with `foreach`? :D

Comment: I am using simple html dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Implode to point the third key in second array

```
$secondArray['profession'] = $first_array[0][0];
$secondArray['contact'] = $first_array[1][0];
$secondArray['address'] = implode(', ', $first_array[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
    $second_array['profession'] = $first_array[0][0];
    $second_array['contact'] = $first_array[1][0];
    $second_array['address'] = $first_array[2][0];
```